# AccessControlException when adding code to MouseMotionListener Java

Tags: java, exception

Recently ive been working on some listeners in an applet in java.  I have had no problems with keylisteners and so I have begun working with mousemotionlisteners.  However, as soon as I added code to the MouseMoved() method, I got an AccessControlException when I ran.  The code compiled fine. Here is the code in the MouseMotionListener:

```
public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e){
     mouseX = e.getXOnScreen();
     mouseY = e.getYOnScreen();
     move();
 }
```

I am doing this on my home computer, but this same code works on the computer at my school.  Here is the exception error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission"      "watchMousePointer")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(MouseInfo.java:79)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:793)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:722)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:379)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Does anybody know why I cannot run this program?  I've read about giving myself permissions but nobody explains how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the SecurityManager, or grant yourself that permission in your .policy file.

Comment: this is the problem, "grant yourself that permission" nobody explains HOW to do it